# Get row in paired sublists by ID

Tags: r

This might be a tricky one:

I need to restructure a list, containing an an unknown number of sublists (although 2 in the sample data). However, each sublist contains an `ID`-Column. For each `ID` in any of the sublists I now need to create a list containing the row where `ID` matches the `ID` in the sublist BUT also the corresponding rows in it's siblings.

This is my initial list:

```
> str(myList1)
List of 2
 $ 1:'data.frame':  2 obs. of  5 variables:
  ..$ ID     : num [1:2] 13369 13599
  ..$ subject: num [1:2] 2 2
  ..$ gender : num [1:2] 1 1
  ..$ age    : num [1:2] 18 18
  ..$ score  : num [1:2] 30 28
 $ 2:'data.frame':  2 obs. of  5 variables:
  ..$ ID     : num [1:2] 13370 14342
  ..$ subject: num [1:2] 3 3
  ..$ gender : num [1:2] 1 1
  ..$ age    : num [1:2] 28 28
  ..$ score  : num [1:2] 27 32
```

This is the result I'm hoping to get:

```
> str(myList2)
List of 4
 $ 13369:List of 2
  ..$ 1:'data.frame':   1 obs. of  5 variables:
  .. ..$ ID     : num 13369
  .. ..$ subject: num 2
  .. ..$ gender : num 1
  .. ..$ age    : num 18
  .. ..$ score  : num 30
  ..$ 2:'data.frame':   1 obs. of  5 variables:
  .. ..$ ID     : num 13599
  .. ..$ subject: num 2
  .. ..$ gender : num 1
  .. ..$ age    : num 18
  .. ..$ score  : num 28
 $ 13370:List of 2
  ..$ 1:'data.frame':   1 obs. of  5 variables:
  .. ..$ ID     : num 14342
  .. ..$ subject: num 3
  .. ..$ gender : num 1
  .. ..$ age    : num 28
  .. ..$ score  : num 27
  ..$ 2:'data.frame':   1 obs. of  5 variables:
  .. ..$ ID     : num 13370
  .. ..$ subject: num 3
  .. ..$ gender : num 1
  .. ..$ age    : num 28
  .. ..$ score  : num 32
 $ 13599:List of 2
  ..$ 1:'data.frame':   1 obs. of  5 variables:
  .. ..$ ID     : num 13369
  .. ..$ subject: num 2
  .. ..$ gender : num 1
  .. ..$ age    : num 18
  .. ..$ score  : num 30
  ..$ 2:'data.frame':   1 obs. of  5 variables:
  .. ..$ ID     : num 13599
  .. ..$ subject: num 2
  .. ..$ gender : num 1
  .. ..$ age    : num 18
  .. ..$ score  : num 28
 $ 14342:List of 2
  ..$ 1:'data.frame':   1 obs. of  5 variables:
  .. ..$ ID     : num 14342
  .. ..$ subject: num 3
  .. ..$ gender : num 1
  .. ..$ age    : num 28
  .. ..$ score  : num 27
  ..$ 2:'data.frame':   1 obs. of  5 variables:
  .. ..$ ID     : num 13370
  .. ..$ subject: num 3
  .. ..$ gender : num 1
  .. ..$ age    : num 28
  .. ..$ score  : num 32
```

I have absolutely no clue on how to achieve this and don't even know where to direct my research on this problem.

Reproducible code:

```
myList1 <- list(
    '1' = data.frame('ID' = c(13369,13599), 'subject' = c(2,2), 'gender' = c(1,1), 'age' = c(18,18), 'score' = c(30,28)),
    '2' = data.frame('ID' = c(13370,14342), 'subject' = c(3,3), 'gender' = c(1,1), 'age' = c(28,28), 'score' = c(27,32))
    )
```

Reproducible code for the outcome, if needed:

```
myList2 <- list(
    '13369' = list('1' = data.frame('ID' = 13369, 'subject' = 2, 'gender' = 1, 'age' = 18, 'score' = 30), '2' = data.frame('ID' = 13599, 'subject' = 2, 'gender' = 1, 'age' = 18, 'score' = 28)),
    '13370' = list('1' = data.frame('ID' = 14342, 'subject' = 3, 'gender' = 1, 'age' = 28, 'score' = 27), '2' = data.frame('ID' = 13370, 'subject' = 3, 'gender' = 1, 'age' = 28, 'score' = 32)),
    '13599' = list('1' = data.frame('ID' = 13369, 'subject' = 2, 'gender' = 1, 'age' = 18, 'score' = 30), '2' = data.frame('ID' = 13599, 'subject' = 2, 'gender' = 1, 'age' = 18, 'score' = 28)),
    '14342' = list('1' = data.frame('ID' = 14342, 'subject' = 3, 'gender' = 1, 'age' = 28, 'score' = 27), '2' = data.frame('ID' = 13370, 'subject' = 3, 'gender' = 1, 'age' = 28, 'score' = 32))
    )
```

Comment: Try `lapply(myList1, function(x) split(x, x$ID))`

Comment: My first thought too but doesn't seem to much the output.

Comment: Maybe `lapply(myList1, function(x) list(split(x, x$ID), split(x[order(x$ID, decreasing = TRUE),], x$ID)))`?

Comment: I have a feeling that your expected output is confusing  For example in the `list` named `13599`, you have `13369` and 13599`.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it is required that each `ID` must be a list of its own AND contain a sublists with it's own data and it's siblings data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick :

```
purrr::flatten(
  lapply(
    myList1, function(l){
      setNames(
        apply(l, 1, function(x){
          setNames(split(l, l$ID),seq_along(l$ID))}), 
        l$ID)}))
```